# Add watermark to image contains in AWS S3 bucket using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is it possible apply watermark on image stored AWS S3 Bucket using PHP?

I have tried with following for retrieve if image exist or not and after watermark applied.

```
    $galleryImg = '_1473241284.jpg';
    // echo $galleryImg;
    test(file_exists('https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/test123/'.$galleryImg));

    //for direct apply watermark on server
    if(file_exists('https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/test123/'.$galleryImg)){
    // test("hiii");
    // echo "hii";
    $watermark->apply('https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/test123/'.$galleryImg, 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/test123/'.$galleryImg, $watermarkImg, 3);

    $response1 = $client->putObject(array('Bucket' => BUCKETNAME, 'Key' => 'bucketname/test123/'.$galleryImg, 'SourceFile' => 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/test123/'.$galleryImg, 'ACL' => 'public-read'));
    //echo "watermark applied";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than applying a watermark and saving the image back to Amazon S3, you could use a third-party service to **apply the watermark on-the-fly**:

- [Watermark with imgix](https://docs.imgix.com/apis/url/watermark/markbase)
- [Watermark with Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/blog/adding_watermarks_credits_badges_and_text_overlays_to_images)

Comment: We can use services like imgix to apply watermark on the fly by sending URL params correspondingly. Given I do not want to expose un-watermarked images, with the above solution the query params can be trimmed and it lets obtain original image. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: @apoorvam This is an old question. Please create a new question rather than asking a new topic in the comments section.